# Kotlin enum Jackson serialization: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.KotlinReflectionInternalError

Tags: enums, kotlin, jackson

I'm getting

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   kotlin.reflect.KotlinReflectionInternalError

in my spring boot rest endpoint when serializing class which contains following enum.

```
enum class Status private constructor(private val code: String) {
    ACTIVE("active"), PENDING("pending");

    companion object {
        fun fromString(value: String): Status {
            return when (value) {
                "active" -> ACTIVE
                "pending" -> PENDING
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Not supported status $value")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to rewrite this enum to Java, and it works ok.

P.S.: I have `compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.+")` dependency in my build.gradle

How to make jackson serialize kotlin's enum class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the @JsonCreator annotation to the companion's #fromString method in order to tell Jackson that it has to use it. And I don't see the @JsonValue annotation either.

```
enum class Status private constructor(@JsonValue val code: String) {
ACTIVE("active"), PENDING("pending");

companion object {

    @JsonCreator
    fun fromString(value: String): Status {
        return when (value) {
            "active" -> ACTIVE
            "pending" -> PENDING
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Not supported status $value")
        }
    }
}
}
```